# absolute position right inside variable width parent div

Tags: html, css

I m having a child div which i want to be positioned as absolute to be at the right upper corner.

By default it is at the left.

The parent div is having a variable width, taking the width of a image inside the div.

The example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kacmn38b/1/)

I cannot use a margin-left as the parent div is having a variable width.

Also using calc failed as 100% in it is taking the page width.

The html -

```
<div class="pic">
<div class="imgc">
<img src="http://nvoids.in/dir/album_image/image_6642.jpeg" />
</div>
<div class="del">
<a href="#">X</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="pic">
<div class="imgc">
<img src="http://nvoids.in/dir/album_image/image_6638.jpeg" />
</div>
<div class="del">
<a href="#">X</a>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS code -

```
.imgc {
  float:left
}

.del {
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    //display:none;
}
.del a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.pic {
  float:left;
}
.pic:hover .del {
  margin-left: 10px;
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.del {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}

.pic {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kacmn38b/2/